# Questions on libc's pointer encryption

Tags: c, security, libc

`glibc` and `eglibc` have a `PTR_MANGLE`, which encrypts pointers in writable memory (more correctly, 'XOR' rather than 'encrypt').

I'm not finding much reading on the feature. `man -k PTR_MANGLE` returns no hits, and Google is returning some superficial chatter. One of the few definitive articles is Drepper's [Pointer Encryption](http://udrepper.livejournal.com/13393.html) on Live Journal.

Is there any in-depth documentation on it? Can it be extended into the user space process, or is it limited to the runtime library? If so, what is the compiler switch or option to enable the feature? Can the feature be disabled in the runtime?

Comment: If no one answers here, try http://security.stackexchange.com/ - I'm also interested in the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`PTR_MANGLE` is an internal feature in glibc, built on macros. It's not automated by the compiler in any way. You could duplicate the same thing in your applications, but you'd also have to do it manually; it works something like:

```
uintptr_t xor_key; // needs to be initialized with random "key" before use
#define PTR_MANGLE(p) (1 ? (void *)((uintptr_t)(p) ^ xor_key) : p)
```

This may be completely different from the glibc implementation; I haven't looked at it in a long time and just wrote this off the top of my head. The seemingly useless use of the conditional operator is to force the resulting expression to have the same type as the original pointer so it can be used directly.

Note that the operation is its own inverse, so `PTR_MANGLE` can be used for both "encryption" and "decryption".

Comment: Interesting.  Your comment about the ternary operator return type has me puzzled.  ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §6.5.15 **Conditional operator** ¶6 says: … _otherwise, one operand
is a pointer to `void` or a qualified version of `void`, in which case the result type is a
pointer to an appropriately qualified version of `void`._  Doesn't that mean that the pointer type is (an appropriately qualified version of) `void *`?  If using GCC (or, presumably, Clang), you could add a cast using `(typeof(p))` and avoid the conditional.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Are you sure none of the earlier clauses apply there? I thought one did.

Comment: The beginning of the paragraph is: _If both the second and third operands are pointers or one is a null pointer constant and the
other is a pointer, the result type is a pointer to a type qualified with all the type qualifiers
of the types referenced by both operands. Furthermore, if both operands are pointers to
compatible types or to differently qualified versions of compatible types, the result type is
a pointer to an appropriately qualified version of the composite type; if one operand is a
null pointer constant, the result has the type of the other operand; otherwise, …_

Comment: I think the _Furthermore_ sentence says 'the return type is `void *`', but I confess I'm not really sure how to prove that.  It might hinge on 'compatible' (and 'composite') types.  That's much earlier in the standard.

Comment: Hmm, gcc and clang seem to agree with what you said. Presumably I was thinking of the case where one of them is a null pointer constant. There might be some way to work around this with additional levels of `?:` operator and null pointer constants, but I don't see it right off.