# Information on glibc heap protection mechanisms?

Tags: c, security, heap-memory, glibc, exploit

Is there any information on what measures glibc takes to make heap-based exploits more difficult?  I've heard of a few things like PTR_MANGLE and some nebulous "heap consistency checking" on the security feature list pages of several Linux distributions, but I've not been able to find detailed information on how these mechanisms are actually implemented, if they are effective, and what vulnerability classes they encompass.  Even when searching for the mentioned features by name I wasn't able to find any glibc documentation on them.

So what features are implemented, and how well do they work?  Does glibc have any kind of heap consistency checking mechanism that is similar to the stack smashing protector on the stack?  Does PTR_MANGLE "encrypt" all pointers, or just a subset of them?  And most importantly, can these features be switched on by the end user, or do they depend on some specific API being used so that I have to hope that whoever wrote the programs I use actually enabled the protection mechanisms?

Comment: Did you try a Google search on 'glibc heap protection', for example?  It comes up with your question first, but the subsequent references are rather useful looking.  (Some, like the Glibc manual, are not as immediately helpful as you'd hope.)  Similarly, 'glibc ptr_mangle' comes up with a lot of useful-looking information.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks, I looked up "glibc ptr_mangle" and found the answer to most of my questions about that.  The only piece of information I couldn't find was whether or not ptr_mangle is enabled for every program compiled with glibc, or whether the person writing the program has to specify that it should be protected by using some special function.  I'd guess that it's an automatic protection, but I can't find anything proving that.  I also wasn't able to find out if glibc implements anything like stack canaries for the heap.

Comment: You could look up [Question's on libc's pointer encryption](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19584160/questions-on-libcs-pointer-encryption) which has a link to another document that may help.

Answer (score 1):

`PTR_MANGLE` is an internal implementation of glibc itself and has no effect on pointers used by programs.  it is also not something that can be turned on/off on the fly or for specific programs.  it only protects internal glibc data structures that are opaque to programs, and even then, it only focuses on ones that can be used to hijack code flow directly (i.e. vtables/function pointers).  it isn't used for general data (e.g. counters).

currently i don't believe glibc is using guard pages for the heap, but people are working on it.  you can try searching the upstream mailing list for recent posts on the topic.  it has long used guard pages for the stack, but those are more for blowing the stack rather than stack canaries (ssp).